Pre Sale on pinksale.finance
Token name: Token on Solana
Decimals: 8
Total supply: 1,000,000 tokens
Token distribution:
Liquidity: 35% (350,000,000 tokens) - Planned to be listed on 7 exchanges, with 50,000,000 tokens per exchange.
Animals & App: 30% (300,000,000 tokens)
Marketing: 20% (200,000,000 tokens)
Team: 15% (150,000,000 tokens)
Community holdings: 200 holders with 10,000 tokens each, totaling 2,000,000 tokens.

How many tokens should be allocated for the pre-sale on each exchange?
What will be the token price during the pre-sale?
What are the SoftCap and HardCap for the pre-sale?"

